# NACL Isn't Loading Modules?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I'm wanting to start developing with NaCl / Pepper and I've gotten my build environment working great, but I can't seem to use any of the examples in my browser.

I've enabled Native Client, debugging, etc. But none of the modules seem to trigger the 'loaded' event, so I have no idea what is going on. This goes for .pexe and .nexe

I have the [git](https://github.com/tyler-elric/coldsteel) here, and I honestly have no idea if there's a problem with my build process, my browser configuration, or what. Has anybody got a clue what's going on here?

This is the closest I've gotten to an error message, and apparently this is a chrome runtime flag, but running chrome with this flag has no effect, and now instead of working, no messages are output.

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling debugging. Enabling debugging means that the NaCl loader will start the Native Client module, and then immediately suspend it and wait for the debugger to connect (then you can resume it with the debugger). So if you don't connect a debugger it will just wait forever. Also if you want to use the debugger on Windows, you need to disable Chrome's sandbox to allow the local TCP connection (for the record, the error message that gets cut off in the screen shot links to the following [chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265624))